# Dokanfuse : how to use Fuse wrapper of Dokan to import a simple file system application of Fuse to windows

Tags: c++, fuse, dokan

I have a simple filesystem created by FUSE on Linux, I wanted to port this to windows using FUSE wrapper of Dokan,

https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/wiki/FUSE
how can I use this, I can't find the dokanfuse.dll file mentioned in the documentation anywhere.

My question is where can I find this dokanfuse.dll file and how can I link it as mentioned in the document.

Comment: Can I raise an issue for this?  why -1 on it?  how can i improve it?

Comment: I wonder what one gets when one runs the source from GitHub through a compiler,

Comment: Windows drivers need to be signed these days. I suppose, you need to install pre-built one from the [releases page](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/releases).

Comment: also , I have tried to find this  using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/using-run-time-dynamic-linking?fbclid=IwAR231OGaEcKSSvyYM5_02sXWNX3P3ExbZSyOebF8dvs8LxTflNNfjNDErjc , still couldn't find it

Comment: I have installed dokansetup.exe file , how can i find .dll file now